# 'LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient)' not returning any location if GPS is off

Tags: android, location, google-api-client, location-services, android-fusedlocation

I'm trying to get user's current location and for that I'm following this [tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/location/retrieve-current.html).

I'm running the following code on a device running Android Lollipop so there's no issue of runtime permission here.

Here's my code (**Update 1.0**):

```
@Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {

    Log.d("onConnected", "called");

    mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
    mLocationRequest.setInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
    mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);

    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);

   }

@Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        mLastLocation = location;
        if (mLastLocation != null) {
            currentLatDouble = mLastLocation.getLatitude();
            currentLngDouble = mLastLocation.getLongitude();

            Log.d("cltLC", String.valueOf(currentLatDouble));
            Log.d("clntLC", String.valueOf(currentLngDouble));
        }
    }
```

here `onConnected` is getting printed out but `clt` and `clnt` is not.

Here's permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```

Here's `build.gradle`:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.0"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.xxx.aaa"
        minSdkVersion 16
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    repositories {
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
    }
    dexOptions {
        javaMaxHeapSize "4g"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:25.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:10.0.1'
    compile 'com.firebase:geofire-android:2.1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

I don't want user to turn on GPS at this stage and want to retrieve current location without it.

I updated the code after seeing this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32568125/6144372), but again nothing is happening if the GPS is OFF!

Please let me know what's the issue here.

Comment: did you enable network location on gps setting?

Comment: @masoudvali are you talking about mobile data or wifi? My mobile data is enabled.

Comment: this will help you http://www.howtogeek.com/211186/how-to-disable-google-location-wi-fi-scanning-on-android/

Comment: @masoudvali what's there in the link to help me, bro? Please explain in details.

Comment: If location mode is set to "off", you can't get a location. The setting must be set to "battery saving" mode in order to use network location provider only.

Comment: @DanielNugent but for that I have to turn on the GPS I don't want to turn it on for retrieving location when user launches the app. The code I had previously was successfully retrieving the location without GPS on devices running android L and below but to make it work on android M and above, I changed the code and now it isn't working even in android L and below.